# Javascript Regx on URL with certain pattern to extract certain parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following problem statement for pure vanilla javascript.

From following different kinds of a URL pattern, extract the value of A, B & C if present without "XX" value where A, B, C is the static word and appear in URL in diff. position.

```
abc.com/fld1/fld2/fld3/A:XX/B:XX/C:XX  - output will be "" (emtpy string as value XX)

abc.com/fld1/fld2/fld3/A:XddX/B:XX/C:we33  - output will be "XddX,we33"

abc.com/fld1/fld2/A:dd,rr,tt/B:ssww,ddd/C:kdkd,dd,d1d  - output will be "dd,rr,tt,ssww,ddd,kdkd,dd,d1d"

abc.com/fld1/fld2/A:dd,rr,tt/C:kdkd,dd,d2d - output will be "dd,rr,tt,kdkd,dd,d2d"

abc.com/fld1/fld2/C:deedd,rdr,t4dadt/B:kddkd,ddd,8udu - output will be "deedd,rdr,t4dadt,kddkd,ddd,8udu"

abc.com/fld1/fld2/C:dd,rr,tt/A:kdkd,d5d,dd6 - output will be "dd,rr,tt,kdkd,d5d,dd6"

abc.com/fld1/fld2/C:dd - output will be 'dd' 

abc.com/fld1/fld2/fld3/B:dddd - output will be 'dddd'
```

I tried following pattern but not sure if I can use nagate to excldue "XX" value or better way to extact values.

```
/(A:)(\w+(,\w+)*)|(B:)(\w+(,\w+)*)|(C:)(\w+(,\w+)*)/ig;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any special reason it needs to be a regular expression? It's relatively straight forward without:

```
function parseValues(urlString) {
  const words = new Set(["A", "B", "C"]);

  const ignore = "XX";

  // Use URL API to get path
  const url = new URL(urlString);
  const path = url.pathname;

  return path.split("/") // Split the path at the slashes
    .map(i => i.split(":")) // split each item of the path at colon
    .filter(i => i.length === 2) // only regard items that had exactly one colon
    .filter(i => words.has(i[0])) // only regard values before the colon that match A, B, C
    .filter(i => i[1] !== ignore) // only regard values after the colon that don't match XX
    .map(i => i[1]) // just take the value after the colon
    .join(","); // join values with commas
}

// Added "http://" to the URLs to make them valid, also StackOverflow requires to use "example.com"

console.log(parseValues("http://example.com/fld1/fld2/A:XX/B:XX/C:XX")); // returns empty string

console.log(parseValues("http://example.com/fld1/fld2/fld3/A:XddX/B:XX/C:we33"));

console.log(parseValues("http://example.com/fld1/fld2/A:dd,rr,tt/B:ssww,ddd/C:kdkd,dd,d1d"));
```

---

EDIT:

Regarding your remarks:

Performance: Unless you have to do this thousands of times a second, performance isn't relevant. Also I doubt this is relevantly slower than a regular exception.

ES5: All currently relevant browsers and other JavaScript environments (especially node) support the used ES6 features. Or there are transpilers and polyfills that will adapt it for you. Or as a last resort, `Set` and `const` can be trivially replaced, and the URL API doesn't need to be used (it's just the proper tool in this case).

Code size: Readability more important than code size. Regular expressions are difficult to add comments to and difficult to read.

> Programs are meant to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute. - *Donald Knuth*

Comment: Thank you for reply. I m looking for performance and Ecma script 5 and code size.

Comment: Thank you for reply